# Dynamic Routing in AngularJS - Can I retrieve data from server before setting up $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Is there any way to make a server hit to retrieve data before setting up all the routes on the `$routeProvider`? I want to be able to dynamically setup routes based on this remote data. I tried something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp").config(["$routeProvider", "$http", function($routeProvider, $http) {
    $http.get("myData").success(function(data) {
        $routeProvider.when(data.dynamicRoute, {
            //route definition
        }
        //or
        $routeProvider.when("/known/route", {
            redirectTo: data.dynamicRoute
        }
    });
}]);
```

but that results in the following error:

```
Unknown provider: $http from myApp
```

So, I understand that the config function is injecting providers and not services. However, I still want to know if I can somehow accomplish my end goal? I don't think I could do this with the `$httpProvider`, but please someone correct me if I'm wrong. If there's some fundamental reason why this just isn't possible, please explain. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: only way to do this is to write your own custom directive and use $location service instead of $routeprovider

Comment: can use `resolve` within `$routeProvider` to make request so nothing else proceeds until your request has completed

Comment: @Ajaybeni - He'd have to rewrite the $route service too.

Comment: @charlietfl - he wants the data before setting up the routes, so a resolve won't work.

Comment: @josh...just trowing it out there...yes that's the way OP code is written, but may not be what is required

Comment: @charlietfl I did look at `resolve` some before posting this, and it wasn't what I was hoping to accomplish. However, I may end up using it, as what I really want to do doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @charlietfl I've began looking at `resolve` to see if it gets me close enough. My question now is, how do I get a hold of the `$http` service to make my request?

Comment: see how it's done in this demo. https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve/blob/master/client/js/app.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

A provider is a configurable service creator. They allow us to provide an API to use to configure their creation. And the configurability is what brings us to `config` blocks. These are used *before* services are available in order to configure their creation. So you can pass settings to `$routeProvider` or `$httpProvider` that it will use when it creates the `$route` and `$http` services, respectively.

Because the services are still being *configured* at this stage, the services themselves are not available for injection - they don't actually exist yet.

The `$routeProvider` allows us to configure routes, which must be running when our application starts. It wouldn't make sense to have routing start at some random point *during* the running of our application.

All this is to say that you can't start running your application, which is what using `$http` would mean, until after the configuration is done. So there's no way to define routes from remote data.

---

For what it's worth, I don't think I see the value in such dynamic routes anyway; they would be unpredictable by nature because they are built from data that is not static. This would totally break bookmarkability, which is the principal purpose of routing.

So I would ask why you feel the need to do this in the first place and then take a step back and see if this is really even the way it should ideally be done.

Feel free to post a comment to provoke further discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the very good explanation. Basically, we have a 2-level nav, and I wanted the route that has only 1 level to then redirect to a configurable (dynamic) 2-level nav. So, if the user goes to "/nav1", it would use the dynamic data to then redirect to "/nav1/dynamicNav2". This is just impossible?

Comment: If you're referring to a default resource (like an article in a blog) then you could use route parameters. First route `/nav1` in the controller fetches the ID of the dynamic resource and then redirects to a second route `/nav/:id`, which loads the identified resource.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a route parameter. The `dynamicNav2` referenced above would be different based on the logged in user.

Comment: Different in what way? Why would different users need different routes?

Comment: I don't know if I want to take the time to explain everything involved here. I can get close enough to what I want with the 'resolve' part of the routing. Thank you again for your explanation and help with all this.

Comment: One reason to have different routes for different users: In a truly RESTful world, each URL corresponds to a specific resource.  http://example.com/userc/preferences is not a route that userb should need to have defined.  Granted, you can do this with URL parameters, as well, so it's not necessarily an earth shattering example, but if you have a ton of data that lives underneath a user's account, then you man not want to constantly deal with the URL parameter.  If you have a zillion routes, do you want to load them all up front?

Comment: @stu.salsbury The problem here is that you are conflating RESTful endpoints with client-side URLs. On the server-side, `/userc/preferences` makes total sense, but from a client side it doesn't. A user already knows his name and he's already authenticated so having it in the URL serves no purpose. The client-side endpoint arguably should be `/preferences`. Anyway, I would argue that if you have a zillion routes you are doing something incorrectly and that URL parameters *should* be used to eliminate that problem.

Comment: As to the first part, sure, a user knows his name... and when that user sends a link to his data to someone else, whose information will the recipient see when they click on the link?  The user id has gotta go somewhere.  I understand that you'd like to argue away the usefulness of server-defined routing, but there really isn't a "problem" here.  If it's not useful to you then certainly don't use it! :)

Comment: @stu.salsbury If a link is shareable, it *must* be defined with a dynamic route. If a site has 300k users, are you going to download 300k routes? Or 300k users times however many user-specific routes? No, of course not. If a link is accessible by more than one user, it *must* contain a dynamic URL parameter - there is no other feasible alternative. Defining them statically simply does not make sense. I'm not trying to "argue away" anything, but so far no one has come up with even a single case where dynamic route definitions make sense.

Comment: With respect, this really isn't the forum to go into detail about the use cases for server-defined, data-driven, or dynamic routing.

Answer (score 8):

This is 100% working solution!

1. Prepare your routes. They might be looked like this ones in json

   ```
   {"0":{"id":1,"when":"/","controller":"MainController","template":"app/views/site/main_inner.html"},"1":{"id":2,"when":"/firm/:firmID","controller":"CompanyController","template":"app/views/site/firm.html"},"2":{"id":3,"when":"/search","controller":"SearchController","template":"app/views/site/search.html"}}
   ```
2. First, you have to make a global reference to RouteProvider

   ```
     var $routeProviderReference;
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

     app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProviderReference = $routeProvider;
     }]);
   ```
3. Second, use method run to do an ajax call for routes.

   ```
      app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$route', function($rootScope, $http, $route) {
       //getting routes
       $http.get('routes.php').success(function (data) {

       angular.forEach(data, function (route) {
           $routeProviderReference.when( route.when, { templateUrl: route.template, controller: route.controller } );
       });
       $routeProviderReference.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
       $route.reload();

   });

   }]);
   ```

For more info look at the ref bellow http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** @dnc253 -- [angular-detour](https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-detour) is now ready enough that I think you could use it to get routes loaded from json. It's not yet well-documented and doesn't have tests, so it's certainly not complete in that sense, but the merging of json into a live instance of the router has been working for a while.

If you're still looking for a way to use server defined routes, you can [read instructions on running the samples](https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-detour/tree/master/samples) and then check out the third sample's [mergeJson call in app.js](https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-detour/blob/master/samples/3-json-config/js/app.js).  Feedback would be great -- I'm getting started on real documentation/tests now, so there's no need to tell me that the documentation sucks and there aren't any tests -- I'm on that one.  :)  Hopefully the samples are enough to squeak by if this functionality is still on your list of needs

**Older part of the answer:** If you just want a static set of routes that are defined by the server with JSON, you could use something like JQuery to fetch your routing data *before* you configure your app.

Pseudocode:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/routes"
  }
}).done(function ( data ) {
    angular
        .module('myApp',[])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
          //read routing instructions from data and call "when" on $routeProvider to define the routes
         });

});
```

This should work with ui-router as well.  But it only enables you to fetch an initial set of routes, so while it gives you the possibility of data-driven definitions, they are only driven by the data that was available when the app was loaded by the client.

As eazel7 points out, you **can** access providers at run time if you create your own service that binds to the provider at config time.  **However**, to do what you want to do you need to go out of process to do an $http call, and with the current routers (the stock Angular core and ui-router) you won't get your answer in time to populate the router before a deep link fails when someone visits your site.  Additionally both of those routers use functions to populate the routing "table" and thus do not lend themselves to having the routing updated after it has been initially configured.

I'm working on something that addresses these issues, such that if a requested route is unknown to the router, it will attempt to fetch it from the server *before* invoking the fallback route or failing.  Also will support checking for modifications to known routes.  Essentially lazy routing with an AJAX/JSON interface to the server.  It's based on ui-router, and is living at https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-detour .  It currently implements the editability of routes but I haven't done the laziness/server communication pieces. That's next on my list. Keep an eye on it, it should end up doing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do such thing is to resolve the routes later, you could ask the routes via json, for example. Check out that I make a factory out of the $routeProvider during config phase, via $provide, so I can keep using the $routeProvider object in the run phase, and even in controllers.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp', []).config(function($provide, $routeProvider) {
    $provide.factory('$routeProvider', function () {
        return $routeProvider;
    });
}).run(function($routeProvider, $http) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $http.get('/dynamic-routes.json').success(function(data) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
        // you might need to call $route.reload() if the route changed
        $route.reload();
    });
});
```